# How to interface usb wifi dongle to stm32f412

Tags: c

For a RT5370 Media Tek USB wi-fi dongle, after running lsusb -v command on linux, we will get its protocol and class. How to procedure further to implement driver on stm32f412.

Comment: which Operating system are you using? and what is stm32f412?

Comment: i am not using any os,stm32f412 is a micro controller.